# How to solve Subtree Isomorphism using maximum bipartite matching?

Tags: algorithm, graph, binary-tree

How do we determine if a given tree T contains subtree that is isomorphic to another tree S?

Two trees are called isomorphic if one of them can be obtained from other by a series of flips, i.e. by swapping left and right children of a number of nodes. Any number of nodes at any level can have their children swapped. Two empty trees are isomorphic.

I've read at few places that bipartiate matching algorithms can be used to solve this problem however I can't find any non-paywalled sources for the details. There seems to be many research papers on this problem, most of them are again behind paywall, however I'm not currently interested in latest research algorithm for this problem. My question is how does bipartiate matching applies to this problem?

PS: There seems to be some confusion on Internet about what is meant by "isomorphic". Above is definition I found at most places but some places mentioned "isomorphic" means trees are of same shape regardless of node values. If someone can clear up this confusion, that had be great too.

Comment: By "tree" you appear to mean an ordered, rooted tree.  By "subtree" do you mean "all vertices and edges reachable from some given vertex" (a.k.a. "the subtree rooted at v" for some vertex v), or "a graph that is obtainable by deleting some edges, and which is a[n ordered, rooted] tree"?  Both definitions are used in different places, but some subgraphs that satisfy the latter don't satisfy the former.

Comment: Yes, let's consider the ordered tree and "the subtree rooted at v". However if bipartite matching is applicable in other scenarios, that would be also interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to talk about rooted subtree isomorphism; the unrooted case can be handled without regard to efficiency by trying all roots.

The basic idea is that if you have trees

```
    A            B
   /|\          /|\
  / | \        / | \
 /  |  \      /  |  \
a1 ...  am   b1 ...  bn
/\      /\   /\      /\
```

and want to know whether `A` is a subtree of `B` in such a way that `A` maps to `B`, then for all `i` and `j`, you compute recursively whether the subtree rooted at `ai` is a subtree of the tree rooted at `bj` in such a way that `ai` maps to `bj`. (The base cases are when `A` or `B` is a leaf.) Now, it's not enough that each subtree be mappable, because if some `bj` has a particularly rich structure, then several `ai`s might be subtrees, but the requirements of isomorphism won't let them share that `bj`. This is where maximum matching comes in: we try to match all of the `ai`s with the `bj`s in such a way that the subtrees can be mapped.

To do the general rooted problem, try all possible choices of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/882995/CCTreeMiner-An-Algorithm-for-Subtree-Mining-Prob), there is a C# implementation of sub-tree isomorphism. A brute force one and I am the coder:)
Hope it can help.

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended. Please provide some examples with explanation.